# How to get parameter value in Jasper chart customizer?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

Is it possible to get parameter values (passed into fillReport method of JasperFillManager) in ChartCustomizer?

Example:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("SOME_PARAM", "some string");

JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params, dataSource);
```

Then in customize function paramValue always null:

```
public void customize(JFreeChart freeChart, JRChart jasperChart) {
  String paramValue = (String)getParameterValue("SOME_PARAM"); // always null
}
```

Expected result: `paramValue` equals to `"some string"`;

Actual result: `paramValue` equals to `null`.

Comment: java-code is correct. Is $P{SOME_PARAM} displayed as "some string" in band, which contain chart? (make Text Field and place it in this band for check)

Answer (score 0):

The method `getParameterValue` refers to chart parameters, these are not the same as report parameters.
In the design, you must define the parameters at the chart level:

```
            <categoryDataset>
                <dataset>
                    <datasetRun subDataset="chartDataset">
                        <datasetParameter name="SOME_CHART_PARAM">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SOME_PARAM}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{XYZ}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                </dataset>
                      .....
            </categoryDataset>
```

And then you should be able to get it with:

```
 getParameterValue("SOME_CHART_PARAM")
```

Comment: which object does provide the  getParameterValue() function ??

Comment: getParameterValue(...) is defined in AbstractChartCustomizer